# Using express JS for logging out a user, how do I correctly send a success response over to Backbone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am learing express JS and backbone.

On the express.js side I have the follwing code which logs out a user:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {

    req.logout();

    res.send('How do I correctly send a success response to the Backbone model?');
});
```

On the Backbone client side, I have created a model which hits: `http://mysite:3000/logout` url.

Here is the code of the model:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var CheckLoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        url : 'http://localhost:3000/logout'
    });

    return CheckLoginModel;
});
```

Now, on the view, I instantiate the model and expect a success or error response:

```
var logoutModel = new LogoutModel(),

logoutModel.fetch({

    success : function (model, xhr, options) {

        // how do I use express to correctly send a success response to Backbone?
    },

    error : function (model, xhr, options) {

    }
});
```

P.S.

In my express code, i could just send some dummy data and I'd be done with it... but I'm not sure that's the correct way:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {

    req.logout();

    res.send({ dummydata : 'dummydata' });

   // not sure sending dummy data like this is the way.
});
```

Any ideas?

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success reflects the http status 200, so you can return `res.send("{}")` (empty json). Also you can define the content-type to application/json in express using in your express route `res.type('application/json');`

Comment: Interesting, for example, I have triend res.send(200) but Backbone did not interpret it corectly. So, I now see that your method makes sense.

Comment: The http status is defined by default by express or the web server that you use, for example if you throw an exception, express will return http status 500 to the browser. But actually with express you can specify it, but it's just in special cases with res.status(code) see more at http://expressjs.com/api.html